# Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist! ",displaying for app with dynamic locators

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

I have the app with dynamic elements and unable to get screenshot for my app error is showing

> Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file:
>   com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!

for other apps UI Automator viewer is working fine.

Please suggest any other tool to get apps locator or any other way? I have stopped Appium and did all the solutions but same issue. **UI Automator** is working fine for other apps.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Please use, appium inspector :https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop

Comment: Thanks, it's working now by using Appium inspector. Thanks @SurajJogdand

Answer (score 2):

That's a pretty common issue with UIAutomatorViewer: it fails to take screen snapshot if layout is dynamicly changing, works fine for static ones.

If you use Appium and Android device with OS 6+ it is not relevant to use UIAuyomatorViewer for elements inspection, as Appium uses UiAutomator2 and element structure may differ.
Use appium-desktop instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please use **appium inspector** for desktop. It will help you to locate the elements.

Please visit [here](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop) for more info.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Appium Inspector actually does a great job locating, but you need to turn it off before running espresso tests, I think the appium server has a lock on the apk during inspection. Any idea how to bypass this?